# Why the value of i is showing at the out of the loop is 5, but in the loop the last value of i is 4?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,n=5;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {   
        printf("in of loop the value of i is %d\n",i);  
    }
    printf("out of loop the value of i is %d",i);
}
```

I can not understand why the value of i is showing at the out of the loop is 5, but in the loop the last value of i is 4.

Comment: It is because loop terminates when `i=5`. When `i` is `4` , loop body executes and when the expression `i++` is executed, `i` becomes `5` and as a result `i<n` evaluates to `false( or 0)`.

Comment: You can have a look at this place - [for loop in C](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_for_loop.htm)

Comment: We are not a tutoring service. Before asking, learn about the constructs you use! This is fundamental stuff.

Answer (score 2):

The for loop increments the value of i at the end of the instruction block. Therefore, when i = 4, the loop runs but at the end, i = 4+1 = 5. At this point, the condition in the loop is no longer satisfied because i now equals to 5.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the for loop as a disguised while loop:

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{   
    do stuff;  
}
```

is equivalent to

```
i=0
while(i<5){
    do stuff;
    i++;
}
```

So at the end, i=5

Comment: Nope. Those two aren't equivalent. One uses `i<5` while the other `i<n`

Comment: Yes, my bad, I just copied-pasted the code in the question. It's corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

in the loop the last value of i is 4，then i++, i is 5, i

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to execute the body of the for cycle 5 
times you should simply consider to do the following correction:

```
for(i=0; i<=n; i++){
/* 
The code here will be executed 5 times.
Subsequently the last printed value will be 5.
*/
printf("in of loop the value of i is %d\n",i);
}
```

What you are observing is due to a mismatch between the value of n and the condition that is evaluated to enter the for cycle. To execute five times the for
cycle n should be **less or equal** to 5.

In this case:

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
printf("in of loop the value of i is %d\n",i);
}
```

When n is equal to 5 it doesn't fulfill the requirement to enter the for loop. The condition here is "Enter the loop if n is less than 5" but it is not considered the case if n is less or equal to 5.

So just use the relational operator "<=" if you wish to execute the cycle 5 times.